# How to move picture box within the window by using mouse pointer in C#.Net

Tags: c#

I am creating an app using C#.Net in Visual Studio 2012. I want to move the picturebox using the mouse. Same as we move icons in our desktop. 
Can anyone help me with the code?

Comment: Can you show what you have tired so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go:

```
    private bool _isMovingControl = false;
    private int _prevMouseX;
    private int _prevMouseY;

    private void pictureBox1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        _prevMouseX = PointToClient(Cursor.Position).X;
        _prevMouseY = PointToClient(Cursor.Position).Y;
        _isMovingControl = true;
    }

    private void pictureBox1_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        _isMovingControl = false;
    }

    private void pictureBox1_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        Point mouseLocation = PointToClient(Cursor.Position);

        if (_isMovingControl && (mouseLocation.X != _prevMouseX || mouseLocation.Y != _prevMouseY) )
        {
            if (mouseLocation.X > _prevMouseX)
            {
                //  Moved cursor to the right;

                pictureBox1.Left = pictureBox1.Left + (mouseLocation.X - _prevMouseX);
                _prevMouseX = mouseLocation.X;
            }
            else if (mouseLocation.X < _prevMouseX)
            {
                //  Moved cursor to the left;

                pictureBox1.Left = pictureBox1.Left - (_prevMouseX - mouseLocation.X);
                _prevMouseX = mouseLocation.X;
            }

            if (mouseLocation.Y > _prevMouseY)
            {
                //  Moved cursor toward the bottom;

                pictureBox1.Top = pictureBox1.Top + (mouseLocation.Y - _prevMouseY);
                _prevMouseY = mouseLocation.Y;
            }
            else if (mouseLocation.Y < _prevMouseY)
            {
                //  Moved cursor toward the top

                pictureBox1.Top = pictureBox1.Top - (_prevMouseY - mouseLocation.Y);
                _prevMouseY = mouseLocation.Y;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: You're welcome!  If it does what you wanted please mark as answer.

Comment: I tried it but its not working :(

Comment: It works like a charm for me.  Did you set the mouseUp, mouseDown and mouseMove events for the pictureBox in your Designer?  Don't change these code blocks.  They work.  You are doing something wrong on your end.

Comment: Yes I also think the same...
I am trying to post my code here.. but Its giving me an error of unformatted code

Answer (score 1):

Condensed version...

```
    private Point StartPoint;

    private void pictureBox1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Button == System.Windows.Forms.MouseButtons.Left)
        {
            StartPoint = new Point(e.X, e.Y);
        }
    }

    private void pictureBox1_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Button == System.Windows.Forms.MouseButtons.Left)
        {
            PictureBox pb = (PictureBox)sender;
            Point pt = pb.Location;
            pt.Offset(e.X - StartPoint.X, e.Y - StartPoint.Y);
            pb.Location = pt;
        }
    }
```

As user1646737 pointed out, you have to wire up the MouseDown() and MouseMove() events to these handlers.  Select the PictureBox.  In the Properties Pane (bottom right by default), click on the "Lightning Bolt" icon to get a list of the events.  Find those events and change the dropdown to the right to the respective methods.  Repeat this for all PictureBoxes.  The code above will work for multiple controls as it uses the `sender` parameter which will be the source control of the event.

Comment: Elegant!  I like it.  Better than mine.